# Django - Catch argument in Class based FormView

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

On my page, i need to display the post detail and a comment form for viewer to post comment. I created 2 generic views:

```
# views.py
class PostDetailView (DetailView):
  model = Post
  context_object_name = 'post'
  template_name = 'post.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comment_form'] = CommentForm()
    return context

class AddCommentView(FormView):
  template_name = 'post.html'
  form_class = CommentForm
  success_url = '/'

  def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(AddCommentView, self).form_valid(form)

  def form_invalid(self, form):
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

detail = PostDetailView.as_view()
add_comment = AddCommentView.as_view()


# urls.py 
....
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', view='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/add_comment/$', view='add_comment'),

....
```

Error would occur in the AddCommentView,since I haven't specified the post's id for the comment. How can I access the post_id in the AddCommentView?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`self.kwargs['post_id']` or `self.args[0]` contains that value

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering)

Comment: You are welcome! If you have more questions please ask. You can also accept this one if find useful

Comment: Thank you! The link to docs does not work, there is no such section in current dev. The latest docs version with the working link is 1.4: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering

Comment: @DennisGolomazov the link is now dead as well

Comment: 2.1 [link] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering